# Iterate dictionary Ansible for certain keys

Tags: ansible, jinja2

a doubt on how to iterate a certain dictionary

```
---
- name: main playbook
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Set fact
      var:
        tower_objects_organizations:
          security:
            org: ORG_I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM
            teams:
              - I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM
              - I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM2
          monit:
            org: ORG_I-SSO-ES-TS-MONIT
            teams:
              - I-SSO-ES-TS-MONIT

    - name: "[{{ productname }}][parallel set organization] Set organizations fact"
      debug:
        msg: "XXXXX"
      with_items: "{{ tower_objects_organizations| dict2items | subelements('value.teams') }}"
```

Does anyone know how could I iterate through the teams in each subdirectionary (security,  monit ...) and to fill a dictionary with the team as key and its org as value, i.e.  `I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM: ORG_I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM, I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM2: ORG_I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM, I-SSO-ES-TS-MONIT:ORG_I-SSO-ES-TS-MONIT`
Using subelements I am capable of reaching the teams list but the output is not the expected one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with and without custom filter:

when i have to do some complex actions on dict i prefer to use a custom filter:

you create a folder **filter_plugins** in your playbook folder (i have named the file **myfilters.py** and the filter **customfilter**)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'customfilter': self.customfilter
        }

    def customfilter(self, obj):
        result = {}

        for k in obj:
            org = obj[k]['org']
            for l in obj[k]['teams']:
                result[l] = org

        return result
```

---

playbook sample:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Set fact
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ tower_objects_organizations | customfilter}}"
      vars:
        tower_objects_organizations:
          security:
            org: ORG_I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM
            teams:
              - I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM
              - I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM2
          monit:
            org: ORG_I-SSO-ES-TS-MONIT
            teams:
              - I-SSO-ES-TS-MONIT
          others:
            org: ORG_I-SSO-ES-TS-OTHER
            teams:
              - I-SSO-ES-TS-OTHER0
              - I-SSO-ES-TS-OTHER1            

    - name: display result
      debug:
        var: result
```

---

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => 
  result:
    I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM: ORG_I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM
    I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM2: ORG_I-SSO-ES-ADM-SSMM
    I-SSO-ES-TS-MONIT: ORG_I-SSO-ES-TS-MONIT
    I-SSO-ES-TS-OTHER0: ORG_I-SSO-ES-TS-OTHER
    I-SSO-ES-TS-OTHER1: ORG_I-SSO-ES-TS-OTHER
```

**EDIT**

another solution without custom filter but less readable i think:

```
- set_fact:
    result: "{{ result | d({}) | combine(dict(item.value.teams|product([item.value.org]))) }}"
  loop: "{{ tower_objects_organizations|dict2items }}"               

- name: debug result
  debug:      
    var: result
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot @Frenchy Do you know why it is not detecting the filter when I am launching in from Ansible Tower?

Comment: maybe ansible tower waits name folder: plugins/filter    in ansible.cfg (/etc/...) you could see a line with #filter_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/filter, so i dont know very well ansible tower